# Exception while Populating Hash Map

Tags: java, hashmap

Class `Test` is my separate class which has two field of `String` and `Float` type, I am using this class with List Collections which will be finally populated as values into `HashMap`.

But when I try to populate the Map with a key and the List objects (values) into the map, Java does not seem to accept it as it is not valid syntax:

```
ArrayList <Test> list = new ArrayList <Test> ();

Map<Integer, ArrayList <Test>> mp = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList <Test>>();  

list.add(new Telephone ( 0.9 , "A"));
list.add(new Telephone(5.1 , "A"));

mp.put(0,list.get(0)); // this Does Not work :(, it should work
```

Output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
The method put(Integer, ArrayList<Telephone>) in the type  
   Map<Integer,ArrayList<Telephone>> is not applicable for the arguments 
   (int,   Telephone) at Main.main(Main.java:64)
```

Comment: `ArrayList <Test> list = new ArrayList <Test> (); ... list.add(new Telephone ( 0.9 , "A"));` shouldn't the compiler complain here?

Comment: @nhahtdh Smart IDE is my guess ;-) (but the exception is: "Unresolved compilation problem" for a reason!)

Comment: @assylias: -_-, it seems that the code is run with -Xint.

Comment: Top tip: don't try to run programs while they're still not compiling. (If this is Eclipse, I'd expect it to prompt you before running, checking that you're really *sure* you want to run a broken program.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going by your requirement you told in comments and question above I think you need following syntax for Map declaration:

```
Map<Integer,Test> mp = new HashMap<Integer,Test>();
```

**EDIT**

OK here is the Edit:

```
ArrayList<Test> list = new ArrayList<Test>();
Map<Integer,ArrayList<Test>> mp = new HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<Test>>();
list.add(new Test(0.1,"A"));
list.add(new Test(0.2,"B"));
mp.put(1,list);
```

and if you again want to put more Test objects at key 1 then do as follows:

```
List<Test> value = mp.get(1);
value.add(0.3,"c");
value.add(0.5,"E");

mp.put(1,value);
```

Comment: ok, this can work, right, but i still would like to know , how to populate  'Map<Integer, ArrayList <Test>> mp = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList <Test>>()'

Comment: Just make me clear that what u want to put as key and as Value in your hashmap?

Comment: For Each key, i want to put multiple objects of the the Class "Test",

i.e. `key=1, i want to put both Object 1: (0.9, "A") and Object 2: (5.1, "A") into the same key`

Answer (score 2):

Your map accepts an Integer as key and ArrayList of Test as value.But instead of arrayList of Test object, you are trying to put Telephone object.
Your IDE is clearly stating that.

```
Map<Integer,ArrayList<Telephone>> is not applicable for the arguments 
   (int,   Telephone) at Main.main(Main.java:64)
```

Comment: Because i don't know the exact syntax to populate this, i know , it was wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

You map can accept only `List` objects as values, while you are trying to put there simple `Telephone` object.

Comment: how should i populate this map, i can not sort out its syntax in java

Comment: I don't know what exactly you want to do. But this, for example, will work: `mp.put(0, list);`

Comment: No, it should not work, i want to key, for each object of List <Test>, the reason is i want to map, each object of Test Class with each unique key.

key=1 , for (0.9, "A") and Key =2 for (5.1, "A")